# Ionic build ios fail

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have a project using Ionic 3 and I execute the following command for build a ios app using XCode 11

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

After that I receive this error message

> Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
>
> cordova build ios exited with exit code 1

In Windows enviroment works normally for Android. Anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Well it looks like it is clearly stating an error in your code of Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined. Have you found where this issue might be?

Comment: @StephenRomero Why the build for android works? I think it is a XCode problem

Comment: Try checking this question I had.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499748/xcode-10-breaks-ionic-cordova-build/52502928#52502928. See if it works for you, if not there might be some type of build issue with xCode 11 specifically.

Comment: you need to identify what is throwing `toLowerCase` undefined error. This cannot be solved unless more info on the cause is provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this options

1)Try to just remove the platform ios and then run below command

```
ionic cordova platform add ios@latest
```

2) Change build system to Legacy Build System from New Build System

Open Xcode --> Select File -->Select Workspace Settings

Comment: Now I have this issue `The following build commands failed:
    CompileAssetCatalog`

Comment: Try removing any icon or splash screen references in the config.xml file;
put a splash.png and/or icon.png files in the www/resources folder of your cordova project; then,
run the ionic cordova resources --icon or ionic cordova resources --splash command

Comment: I did it but without success